# need help styling dashicon in admin bar

Tags: admin-bar

I am adding my custom post type to the admin bar for the convenience of the end user. I added an icon to it with the following code,

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_node(
    array(
        'title'  => '<span class="dashicons-before dashicons-universal-access" style="padding-top:13px;">Careers</span>'
    )
);
```

which works, but needs more styling. The padding-top isn't working, as you can see below. I've tried every other style I can think of but nothing affects it.

[image: floating person]

Comment: You're adding `padding` to the `span` which contains the text and icon, the icon is a pseudo and needs a `margin-top` property, something like this: `.ab-top-menu span.dashicons-universal-access:before {margin-top: 6px}`. PHP: `add_action('admin_footer', function() { 
    print '<style type="text/css">.ab-top-menu span.dashicons-universal-access:before {margin-top: 6px}</style>' . PHP_EOL;
});`

Comment: @SamuelElh I'm having trouble implementing this. I understand it as   'title'  => '<span class="dashicons-before dashicons-universal-access:before {margin-top: 6px}" >Careers</span>', but that doesn't work either.

Comment: No, you just use this custom CSS `.ab-top-menu span.dashicons-universal-access:before {margin-top: 6px}` in your custom CSS file

Comment: @SamuelElh it's probably a side effect of the fact that I've added this functionality to my theme, rather than a plugin, but this works perfectly when viewing the site, but when on the admin page it no longer works. Moving it to a plugin is a high priority, so if that's the issue I'll live with it for now.

Comment: Probably the custom CSS is only added when in front-end (theme stylesheet) and you need to add this custom CSS to admin as well, e.g adding this to child-functions file `add_action('admin_head', ..` (first comment)